# Unable to persist collection object using Mutiny Panache library in Postgres

Tags: reactive-programming, quarkus-panache, mutiny

In my backend application, I am using Mutiny reactive library in combination with Quarkus to persist data in Postgres. I am able to persist single row data using persistAndFlush() but while I try to persist list using persist(Collection) , it fails. However there is no exception/error from database calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (it works with hibernate-reactive, but can be used in conjunction with panache):

```
@Inject
Mutiny.SessionFactory sf;

public Uni<List<T>> createAll(List<T> t) {    
  return sf.withTransaction(
      (s, t) -> s.persistAll((Object[]) t.toArray(new T[0]))
          .replaceWith(t));
}
```

Note that you **may** need to parse the collection to vargars. (As it is shown above)